# Что делать, если не хочется программировать?

Tags: обсуждение, диалоги-о-работе

Эх.. Проблема дикая. В общем, помню как 3 года назад начал писать под Android. С огромным рвением. Сейчас мне 18 и все это пропало. Оцениваю себя сильным джуниором или слабым миддлом. Не знаю в разработке - сервисы, уведомления, виджеты, бродкасты. В последнее время почти постоянно смотрю чужой код на гитхабе. Но все же сам я ничего такого крупномасштабного не написал, библиотеки особо не использую. Как возьмусь за что-то - сразу нахожу в маркете то же самое, в 100500 раз лучше. Сразу желание пропадает кодить...

Все больше смотрю сейчас в сторону PHP. Скажите, стоит ли туда суваться? Или остаться на андроиде? Тогда как лечить эту мою выходку?

Comment: `Тогда как лечить эту мою выходку?` — трудоустройством или фрилансом по Android-разработке. Поймите, вы хотите сунуться в совершенно другой, чуждый мобильному, мир серверной web-разработки; мир со своими законами, писаными и неписаными правилами и особенностями.

Comment: Займитесь чем-нибудь другим (можно в футбол поиграть)

Comment: А вот от кодинга не охота отворачиваться

Comment: @Arhad, хм. Php это не ООП?

Comment: @Flippy, PHP (как и web-разработка в общем) — это массовое обслуживание множества клиентов, ограниченные возможности хранения информации индивидуально о каждом из них, богатые возможности по передаче вредоносных данных (SQL-инъекции и XSS). Также это необходимость грамотной настройки связки frontend-backend (чтобы не лечь под более-менее серьёзной нагрузкой). Наконец, помимо PHP вам придётся изучать HTML (поддержка возможностей которого разными версиями разных обозревателей является отдельным разговором), CSS и, возможно, JS в довесок. **Потому я и отметил, что это совершенно другой мир.**

Comment: Окей, вы меня вдохновили :) прямо сейчас возьмусь и напишу морской бой, потом изучу все, что не знаю и буду пробовать себя на фрилансе :D

Comment: @Flippy, к тому же сейчас ваша программа работает на устройстве пользователя, надёжно хранит в нём все настройки, плюс может получить доступ к любому файлу или железке (при наличии разрешения, но может). В web-разработке же у вас есть один скрипт на огромное количество пользователей сразу, очередь совершенно несвязанных запросов (да, HTTP не хранит состояние в рамках подключения, у него вообще нет понятия сессии), серверная база данных в качестве хранилища да легкостираемые куки на стороне клиента (небольшие текстовые фрагменты ограниченного срока действия, привязанные к конкретному браузеру).

Comment: @Flippy, в придачу в вебе вы работаете не с устройствами, а с *запросами*. Предел мечтаний — встроить в отправляемую страницу скрипт на JS, который будет исполняться в железобетонно ограниченной песочнице безо всяких поблажек.

Comment: Ой, ну его, этот веб, испугался чет :)

Comment: @Flippy, это была краткая зарисовка того, *насколько* отличается мобильная разработка от web-разработки.

Comment: А вы сами веб-программист?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53514/discussion-between-flippy-and-arhad).

Comment: `Не знаю в разработке - сервисы, уведомления, виджеты, бродкасты`. Ничего личного, но что-то мне подсказывает, что у Вас какое-то неправильное представление о сильном джуниоре и слабом миддле (*или у меня*).

Comment: @Flippy только в РHP не идите...

Comment: @PashaPash, на страже чистоты кода...

Comment: И почему именно php, чем больше вы попробуете тем лучше. может найдете то что вам будет действительно по душе и главное, на чем найдется что сделать стоящего. И чем больше кругозор тем проще в будущем осваивать новое

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Когда я был на втором курсе университета (и примерно в том же возрасте), обнаружил себя в похожей ситуации. И тоже задал похожий вопрос на одном известном форуме. Мне кто-то ответил в духе "Не хочется — не программируй. Если вернется желание — значит вернется, нет — значит не твоё." Я подумал тогда: чушь какая-то. А сейчас дам вам тот же совет.

Comment: Спасибо. Я просто зашёл в код и не вернулся.

Comment: @Flippy не за что. Успехов!

Answer (score 2):

Может быть, вам необходимо разобраться чего вы хотите на самом деле. Предлагаю такую технику:

В течении трёх месяцев, вы каждый день, как просыпаетесь, записываете 10 ваших целей, чего бы вам хотелось. Цели можно менять.

Это позволит вам понять, или немного приблизиться к пониманию чего вы хотите. А потом всё просто, поймёте что хотите, и будете просто делать.